apache - mod_remoteip enabled nftables cannot block defined IPs
On raspeberry with debian bullseye, before I make the needed changes to log the visitor IP via cloudfare, nftables played OK..
At the time enabled the mod_remoteip and add those
at  /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RemoteIPHeader CF-Connecting-IP

at /etc/apache2/conf-available/remoteip.conf
RemoteIPHeader CF-Connecting-IP
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 103.21.244.0/22

nftables stop blocking the defined IPs...
the nftables.conf is like
table ip filter {
    set blacklist {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags interval
        auto-merge
        elements = { 1.34.128.0/17, 3.224.0.0/12, }
    }

    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        ip saddr @blacklist drop
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        ip saddr @blacklist drop
    }
}
table ip6 filter {
    set blacklist {
        type ipv6_addr
        flags interval
        auto-merge
        elements = { 2001:bc8:701::/48,
                 2001:41d0:801:2000::/64, }
    }

    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        ip6 saddr @blacklist drop
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        ip6 saddr @blacklist drop
    }
}

using it as
sudo nft flush ruleset
~# sudo nft -f /etc/nftables.conf
~# sudo systemctl status nftables
● nftables.service - nftables
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nftables.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited)
       Docs: man:nft(8)
             http://wiki.nftables.org
    Process: 46412 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nft -f /etc/nftables.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 46412 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 59ms

Oct 15 18:45:12 x systemd[1]: Starting nftables.service - nftables...
Oct 15 18:45:12 x systemd[1]: Finished nftables.service - nftables.

--SOLUTION block on apache
    <Directory /var/www>
        <RequireAll>
            Require all granted
            Require not ip 1.34.128.0/17
            Require not ip 3.224.0.0/12
        </RequireAll>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


What is your question?

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' as the title says "nftables cannot block defined IPs" when used with reverse proxy.. the only solution is to block on apache level.

Yes. And the trouble is not so much with mod_remoteip alone, or nftables alone, but the structural setup: once you enable mod_remoteip, what httpd sees as the remote IP is not the IP that makes a network connection to your host. (That IP is still available as %{c}a for logging purposes, according to the docs.)
And that means you're probably still adding entries to the blocklist (in some way that I think I can't see from what you've told us), but that doesn't help, because they weren't connecting to your server in the first place. Assuming that you don't want to block the cloudflare servers, your path forward would be a mechanism that instead of adding to your local nftables issues some sort of API call to Cloudflare to block the original IP for you. (I have no idea if they do that, I have the same problem with internal load balancing servers where I have more/different options.)

finally I add apache directive

nftables cannot manage IPs by reverse proxy.
